# rescaling axes on pcolor plot from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm inputting data from a text file with column structure more or less like this:

```
x   y   density
```

I need to plot a heat map of density(x,y).

I'm just getting started with pyplot and pandas and I'm not sure how to achieve this functionality efficiently.

I first tried just loading in the columns and plotting with

```
plt.pcolor( OrbData[['x']], OrbData[['y']], OrbData[['density']]  )
```

but this failed because the color values must be in an array.  So now I'm using the x,y values as a multi-index and unpacking the data frame.

Here is my script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Morbs = 2 
OrbFile = "69.0000000orbs.dat"

### Load in the data using pandas
OrbData = pd.read_csv(OrbFile, sep='\s+', usecols = [ 0, 1, 7 ], header= None, names=['x','y','density'], skiprows=2)
OrbData = OrbData.set_index(['x','y'])
OrbData=OrbData.unstack()

plt.figure(1)
plt.pcolor(OrbData[['density']], cmap='hot')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

this almost works perfectly, but the axes in the plot show the record number (0,50) rather than the index values (-2,2).

If I try `plt.pcolor(OrbData[['x']], OrbData[['y']], OrbData[['Mag1']], cmap='hot')`  with the unpacked data, I get an error 
`KeyError: "['x'] not in index"`.

If I try to access the index values using `OrbData.index` I only recover the x-values (rows), and I can't figure out how to access the y-values (columns).

There are several ways I can think to do this, but they all feel hacky and inefficient.

1) save the x,y columns separately before the unpack

2) transpose the dataframe and use OrbData.index to get the y-values

3) manually rescale the axes in pyplot somehow

I'm trying to make ~10^5 plots for animations and each plot has at least 10^4 records so I need something that isn't too wasteful.
there must be some simple way to pull the values from the column data in a format that pcolor can read.

any ideas?

Comment: use the matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf method: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf.html                     this delivers you a 3D image with x and y as axis (1. and 2. dimension) and the density as third dimension. If you adjust the cmap parameter you can plot different colours for the density

Comment: The reason you do not get a satisfying answer here is that people have no idea how your data is organized and how it looks like. Please provide a [mcve] and a clear problem description.

Answer (score -1):

This code snipped is out of the Python data science handbook from Jake VanderPlas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
y=np.linspace(0,10,100)

def density(x,y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x)*np.cos(x)

X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z=density(X,Y)


plt.contourf(X,Y,Z,cmap="magma")


plt.show()
```

This approach yields results like this:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer, but I don't think this addresses the question.

I need to find a way to pull the X,Y data out of the pandas data frame.